# D3 Charts - JS - Adding Hours To Time

Tags: javascript, d3.js, charts

Hoping to get some guidance around this.

I am playing around with this - https://codepen.io/HD10805/pen/QoaVdL

In the JS element, there's a section where I believe the data for the Time is generated and compiled.

```
function renderTime() {

var now = new Date();
var today = now.toDateString();
var time = now.toLocaleTimeString();
var hours = now.getHours();
var minutes = now.getMinutes();
var seconds = now.getSeconds();
var milliseconds = now.getMilliseconds();
var newSeconds = seconds+ (milliseconds/1000);
```

Essentially, I would like to be able to add or subtract hours in order to display the times of other countries in other time zones.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you add more detail on what is going wrong please?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [**setHours**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/setHours)

```js
let date = new Date()

console.log(date)

let hours = date.getHours()

date.setHours(2 + hours)

console.log(date)
```

Comment: Hey Code Maniac, thanks for the quick response.

I'm not quite sure how to incorporate this into the code without breaking the chart.

I did try to use setHours a different way, but I wasn't successful.

var hours = now.setHours(now.getHours() + 1);